# Entity Framework Code First Zero to Many

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Candidate who can (or cannot) have many JobTypes, I would expect an intermediary table of CandidateJobTypes.

This is a zero to many relationship.

How would this be modelled with Entity Framework code first?

*Models*

```
public class Candidate
{
    [Required]
    public long CandidateId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CandidateJobType> CandidateJobTypes { get; set; }
}

public class CandidateJobType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long CandidateId { get; set; }

    public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; }

    public long JobTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual JobType JobType { get; set; }
}

public class JobType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public long? ParentJobTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual JobType ParentJobType { get; set; }
}
```

*OnModelCreating*

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // not sure what goes in here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it like one to many. Nobody cares the collection is empty.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CandidateJobType>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.Candidate)
    .WithMany(m = m.CandidateJobTypes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need anything in `OnModelCreating`? You followed convention just fine. Everything should work just fine

Comment: I get the following error when there is nothing in OnModelCreating and I try to save:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[Temps.Models.CandidateJobType, Temps, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot be set or removed from the Value property of an EntityReference of type 'Temps.Models.CandidateJobType'.